# The lib is failed to link in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I use  Qt 4.10.0 in 64-bit windows 7.
When I tried to compile my project, error occurs:
:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_71.lib'

But I do have this line in my .pro file and I have checked that the lib file (32-bit)  is in this folder

```
LIBS += -L"D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/boost_1_71_0/libs" - 
llibboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_71 \
```

I use boost boost_1_71_0  in my project.

Comment: You are on Windows. Maybe it should be simply: `LIBS += D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/boost_1_71_0/libs/libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_71.lib` instead?

Comment: I use your method but get another error: :-1: error: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'D:\EPS_projects\2018to2019\29_IOT_MDI\boost_1_71_0\libs\libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_71.obj'

Comment: You state that you are using a 64 Windows 7, what architecture is your compiler, 32 or 64 bit. This matters since you specify that your lib is 32 bit, so hopefully the compiler is also 32 bits

Comment: The complier is 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `-l` notation, due to the way that qmake tries to be platform independent, you only need to supply the library name, without the first 'lib'.

Thus try the following:

```
LIBS += \ 
  -L"D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/boost_1_71_0/libs" \
  -lboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_71
```

PS: The indenting is just for readability, you can keep it in one line